# Typescrtipt: Conditionally deciding types depending on props sent

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a function that accepts a theme object, which contains different themes. Each theme property contains an object with certain properties.

```
type ThemeNames = "light" | "dark" | "punk";

type Properties = {
  backgroundColor: string;
  labelColor: string;
}

const themeObject = {
  light: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    labelColor: 'white',
  },
  dark: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    labelColor: 'white',
  },
  punk: {
    backgroundColor: 'purple',
    labelColor: 'yellow',
  },
}
```

I would like a type that would accept the theme object in these certain scenarios:

- Contains all themes `light` `dark` and `punk`, and they all have the `Properties`.
- Contains some of the themes, in which case a `default` property must be passed, which contains all the `Properties` inside.
- `light` `dark` or `punk` have some properties missing, in which case `default` must contain them.

Currently, I have a type which just accepts all the themes.

```
type ProcessTheme<T> = {
  [key in ThemeNames]: T;
};
```

And I pass the `Properties` to the function as a generic.

Is there a way to type some of this or all of this?

Answer (score 0):

We want to accept an object which will have only some of the keys of `ThemeNames`.  The value for each key is a complete or partial `Properties` object.  That gives us this type:

```
type PartialThemeObject = Partial<Record<ThemeNames, Partial<Properties>>>
```

Now for a given `PartialThemeObject`, we want to figure out what the corresponding `defaults` needs to include.

If a `ThemeName` has a complete `Properties` object then we don't need to include that theme name in the `defaults`.  So let's find the keys that are incomplete:

```
type IncompleteKeys<T extends PartialThemeObject> = {
    [K in ThemeNames]: T[K] extends Properties ? never : K;
}[ThemeNames]
```

For each of those `IncompleteKeys` we need to know which properties we need to set in `RequiredDefaults`

```
type RequiredDefaults<T extends PartialThemeObject> = {
    [K in IncompleteKeys<T>]: /* what goes here? */;
}
```

If there was no value at all in the partial theme, then we need all properties.

```
T[K] extends undefined ? Properties : /* */
```

If some values were set, then we just need the ones that weren't set.  That is basically
`Omit<Properties, keyof T[K]>`
This next step is not really required in the practical sense because the generic type `T` is going to be inferred from the object, so it won't infer any properties as optional.  But if you are passing in a partial theme that has a pre-defined type then the above definition isn't fully accurate.  When we are omitting keys, we only want to omit keys that are required in `T[K]` so that optional keys are needed in the defaults.  We can use a `RequiredKeys` utility type as a helper

```
type RequiredKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Required<T>[K] ? K : never;
}[keyof T]
```

Putting that all together, the type for the required defaults is

```
type RequiredDefaults<T extends PartialThemeObject> = {
    [K in IncompleteKeys<T>]: T[K] extends undefined ? Properties : Omit<Properties, RequiredKeys<T[K]>>;
}
```

Our function should require all those defaults but also allow any other optional defaults so we will join that with `PartialThemeObject`.

This signature covers your second and third situations:

```
function processTheme <T extends PartialThemeObject>(
    theme: T, defaults: RequiredDefaults<T> & PartialThemeObject
) { }
```

In order to make the second argument optional in your first scenario while keeping it required in the other two, we need to use function overloading.  We will have one overload that covers the first scenario, one for the second and third, and then the last line of an overloaded function signature is the implementation.

```
type CompleteTheme = Record<ThemeNames, Properties>

function processTheme ( theme: CompleteTheme, defaults?: PartialThemeObject ): CompleteTheme;
function processTheme <T extends PartialThemeObject>( theme: T, defaults: RequiredDefaults<T> & PartialThemeObject ): CompleteTheme
function processTheme <T extends PartialThemeObject>( theme: T, defaults: PartialThemeObject = {} ): CompleteTheme {
    return {
        ...defaults,
        ...theme
    } as CompleteTheme
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/oN5g9W)

Comment: Ahh sorry, wasn't very clear on how I wanted to pass the default theme, as I meaning to pass it as a new property in the theme object called `default`. I will give it a try to see if I can transform this code to work with that.